# Matching all pairs of 2 vectors to third column

Tags: r

I have this data.frame :

```
x1=c(1,2,3,4,5)
values=c(1.5,2.2,1.1,2.3,1.1)
d=data.frame(x1,values)
```

I devided `x1` to

```
x=c(1,2)
y=c(3,4,5)
```

and then I calculate all pairs using `expand.grid`

```
e=expand.grid(x=x,y=y)

> e
  x y
  1 3
  2 3
  1 4
  2 4
  1 5
  2 5
```

My question is how to calculate a third column that gives values(x)/values(y) ??
Like :

```
  x y values_1
  1 3 1.5/1.1
  2 3 2.2/1.1
  1 4 1.5/2.3
  2 4 2.2/2.3
  1 5 1.5/1.1
  2 5 2.2/1.1
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use square brackets:

```
e$newcol <- with(e,values[x]/values[y])
```

or similarly

```
e$newcol <- values[e$x]/values[e$y]
```

which makes `e`:

```
  x y    newcol
1 1 3 1.3636364
2 2 3 2.0000000
3 1 4 0.6521739
4 2 4 0.9565217
5 1 5 1.3636364
6 2 5 2.0000000
```

To find out more, type `help.start()`, navigate to the "Introduction to R" document and its section on "Index vectors; selecting and modifying subsets of a data set".